# Making Gridview responsive

Tags: flutter

I have created a custom Widget to show a gridview.

```
class ListaGrid4x2Experiencias extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListaGrid4x2Experiencias({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListaGrid4x2Experiencias> createState() =>
      _ListaGrid4x2ExperienciasState();
}

class _ListaGrid4x2ExperienciasState extends State<ListaGrid4x2Experiencias> {
  List<Experiencia>? listaExperiencias = ListasFake.listaFakeExperiencias;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          childAspectRatio: 5 / 5,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5),
      itemCount: listaExperiencias!.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
        Experiencia experiencia = listaExperiencias![index];

        return new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: BoxExperienciaMuro(
              imagenPrincipal: experiencia.imagenPrincipal,
              denominacion: experiencia.denominacion,
              ubicacion: experiencia.ubicacion,
              unidadTiempo: experiencia.unidadTiempo,
              precioUnitario: experiencia.precioUnitario,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I need to make it responsive.

The user will use the app mostly on a navigator, so that the items should be shown in as many rows and columns as the screen allows depending on screen width and without changing the item aspect.

With the current code, the items are shown as follows in a screen width from 1042 px:

[image]

But making the screen wider, the items are distorted

[image]

Here you have BoxExperienciaMuro code:

```
class BoxExperienciaMuro extends StatefulWidget {
  const BoxExperienciaMuro({
    Key? key,
    required this.imagenPrincipal,
    required this.denominacion,
    required this.ubicacion,
    required this.unidadTiempo,
    required this.precioUnitario,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String imagenPrincipal;
  final String denominacion;
  final String ubicacion;
  final String unidadTiempo;
  final String precioUnitario;

  @override
  State<BoxExperienciaMuro> createState() => _BoxExperienciaMuroState();
}

class _BoxExperienciaMuroState extends State<BoxExperienciaMuro> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String urlImagen = Constantes.imagenesExperiencias + widget.imagenPrincipal;
    double anchoPantalla = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    //la proporcion del ancho total de pantalla al ancho todal del container es del 6% a cada lado, un total del 12%
    //la proporcion del ancho total de pantalla al ancho todal de cada experiencia

    double anchoExperiencia = (anchoPantalla - (anchoPantalla*0.12)) / 4.6;



    return Container(

      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(
                width: anchoExperiencia,
                height: 130,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage(urlImagen))),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                  child: BoxPercentProgressPlazasDisponibles()
              )
            ]),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      width: anchoExperiencia,
                      height: 15,
                      child:
                          TextoNormalNegroNegrita(texto: widget.denominacion)),
                  Container(
                      width: anchoExperiencia,
                      height: 15,
                      child: TextoNormalNegroNormal(texto: widget.ubicacion)),
                  Container(
                      width: anchoExperiencia,
                      height: 15,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          TextoNormalNegroNegrita(texto: widget.unidadTiempo),
                          TextoNormalNegroNegrita(texto: widget.precioUnitario)
                        ],
                      )),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could be issue with `anchoExperiencia` and its custom size, you can try removing all fixed size from `BoxExperienciaMuro `

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, yes, I will try removing all fixed sizes